# How to speed up rendering chart in vue.js component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I've got a Vue component that renders another component when the user clicks on an image.  It behaves like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/james2doyle/qsQun/), except instead of seeing the #2 when the card turns over, the user sees a chart.

The code looks like this.

```
<div class="card" v-on:click="flipCard()" v-bind:class="{ flipped: isFlipped }">
  <div class="front">
    <img src="something.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    <BarChartTile :sourceData="chartData" :options="chartOptions"></BarChartTile>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem I'm having is that when the user clicks on the card for the first time, the graph takes too long to render.  Vue.js isn't pushing the graph's source data over to Chart.js until the user has clicked the card but right now it takes just enough time for the user to notice that things are going slowly.

Once the graph component has rendered once, everything is fine.  The user can click the card over and over and the graph will appear/disappear fluidly and without delay.

Is there a way to tell Vue.js to do the work to render the child component but just not show it until the user clicks the card? Or, is there an alternate implementation of this card-flipping behavior that avoids the issue I'm experiencing?

Comment: no idea why someone downvoted this?

Comment: Given this template, nothing is blocking the rendering of the bar chart before it is flipped.  Are you getting the data when the user clicks or something else that could be impacting when the chart data is actually available?  You can see a test of it already being render before the flip in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2fucrygj/).

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  The issue turned out to be caused by CSS.  Vuejs was as performant as ever.  It was my goofy CSS that was problematic.